# pyautocad gives ungooglable error

Tags: python, python-3.6, autocad

> OSError: [WinError -2147221005] Invalid class string

full traceback

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MONSTR/Desktop/Ванжые/Yusuf bey/GUI/test1.py", line 10, in <module>
    for text in acad.iter_objects('Text'):
  File "C:\Users\MONSTR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyautocad\api.py", line 111, in iter_objects
    block = self.doc.ActiveLayout.Block
  File "C:\Users\MONSTR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyautocad\api.py", line 74, in doc
    return self.app.ActiveDocument
  File "C:\Users\MONSTR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyautocad\api.py", line 67, in app
    self._app = comtypes.client.CreateObject('AutoCAD.Application', dynamic=True)
  File "C:\Users\MONSTR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 227, in CreateObject
    clsid = comtypes.GUID.from_progid(progid)
  File "C:\Users\MONSTR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\comtypes\GUID.py", line 78, in from_progid
    _CLSIDFromProgID(str(progid), byref(inst))
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 918, in GetResult
OSError: [WinError -2147221005] Invalid class string
```

I get this error when I am trying to compile this code from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyautocad/)

```
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint

acad = Autocad()
acad.prompt("Hello, Autocad from Python\n")
print(acad.doc.Name)

p1 = APoint(0, 0)
p2 = APoint(50, 25)
for i in range(5):
    text = acad.model.AddText('Hi %s!' % i, p1, 2.5)
    acad.model.AddLine(p1, p2)
    acad.model.AddCircle(p1, 10)
    p1.y += 10

dp = APoint(10, 0)
for text in acad.iter_objects('Text'):
    print('text: %s at: %s' % (text.TextString, text.InsertionPoint))
    text.InsertionPoint = APoint(text.InsertionPoint) + dp

for obj in acad.iter_objects(['Circle', 'Line']):
    print(obj.ObjectName)
```

After few hours on google, I decided to wonder here
What can be the reason ?

Comment: Please include the full traceback. I have found that error code but no idea if what I'm reading is relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That specific error occurs because your program can't open AutoCAD properly; but when I open AutoCAD by myself and then run your code, it appears the following error:

```
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147467262, 'No compatible interface', (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

In my experience, `COMError` often appears due to a poor connection with the used program. I solve that kind of problem by combining `win32com` with `pyautocad`. For this particular case, it would be something like this:

```py
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
import win32com.client

AutoCAD = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists = False)

p1 = APoint(0, 0)
p2 = APoint(50, 25)

for i in range(5):
    text = acad.model.AddText('Hi %s!' % i, p1, 2.5)
    acad.model.AddLine(p1, p2)
    acad.model.AddCircle(p1, 10)
    p1.y += 10

dp = APoint(10, 0)
for text in acad.iter_objects(['Hi']):
    print('text: %s at: %s' % (text.TextString, text.InsertionPoint))
    text.InsertionPoint = APoint(text.InsertionPoint) + dp

for line in acad.iter_objects(dont_cast = True):
    print(line.ObjectName)

AutoCAD.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had Autocad LT and it appeared to be a compatibility problem. AutoCAD LT is not compatible with pyautocad.