# OSError: Invalid Class String

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, comtypes

I am trying to use pyautocad to automate some tasks in AutoCAD Application. I get the acad object correctly, hence its return "<pyautocad.api.Autocad object at 0x015673A0>" but get an error when i try to manipulate this object in any way. The error is shown below. I tried reinstalling pywin32, also tried installing pypiwin32. Does anyone know how could i fix this error and succesfully manipulate the acad application?

My code is simple and as follows:

```
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint

acad = Autocad()
p1 = APoint(0, 0)

print(acad)
print(p1)

acad.prompt("Hello, Autocad from Python\n")

for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    obj = acad.model.AddText('Hi %s!' % i, p1, 2.5)
    p1.y += 10

#EXECUTION THROUGH CMD
C:\tcc>python teste.py
<pyautocad.api.Autocad object at 0x015673A0>
APoint(0.00, 0.00, 0.00)
Hello, Autocad from Python

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tcc\teste.py", line 9, in <module>
    acad.prompt("Hello, Autocad from Python\n")
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pyautocad\api.py", line 162, in prompt
    self.doc.Utility.Prompt(u"%s\n" % text)
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pyautocad\api.py", line 74, in doc
    return self.app.ActiveDocument
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pyautocad\api.py", line 63, in app
    self._app = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject('AutoCAD.Application', dynamic=True)
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 173, in GetActiveObject
    clsid = comtypes.GUID.from_progid(progid)
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\GUID.py", line 78, in from_progid
    _CLSIDFromProgID(str(progid), byref(inst))
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 947, in GetResult
OSError: [WinError -2147221005] Invalid class string
```

I also tried a solution to a question asked here before (this is the link: [pyautocad gives ungooglable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826570/pyautocad-gives-ungooglable-error), which seems to have worked that time, but for me it gives the same error.

```
C:\tcc>python teste.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tcc\teste.py", line 4, in <module>
    AutoCAD = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```